# Is it possible to apply different class and attribute on individual label in crispy-forms?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I am using crispy-forms for the first time. And i want to use separate `css_class` for each label according to their length. And also want to use css property for label and their respective fields. I tried various methods but not succeeded. Please Help me out.

> forms.py

```
''' ~~~ Import Statements ~~~ '''
from django import forms 
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, Layout, Field ,Fieldset,Div,Row,Reset,Button
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import (PrependedText, PrependedAppendedText,InlineField, FormActions)


class student_personal_infoForm(forms.Form):

first_name = forms.CharField(label="First Name",required=True,max_length=20, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'First Name', 'required':True}))
middle_name = forms.CharField(label="",required=False,max_length=20, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Middle Name'}))
last_name= forms.CharField(label="", required=True,max_length=20,widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Last Name', 'required':True}))

father_name = forms.CharField(label="Father's Name", required=True,max_length=20,widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Father Name', 'required':True}))
mother_name = forms.CharField(label="Mother's Name", required=True,max_length=20,widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Mother Name', 'required':True}))

helper = FormHelper()
helper.form_method = 'POST'
helper.label_class = 'col-md-4'
helper.form_class = 'form-inline'
helper.field_class = 'col-md-4 control-label'
helper.layout = Layout(
Div(
    Row(  
        Field('first_name',css_class='control-label'),
        Field('middle_name',css_class='control-label'),
        Field('last_name',css_class='control-label'),
        css_class='row-fluid divs panel')
  ),
Div(
    Row(
        Div(
            Field('father_name', css_class='control-label'), 
            css_class='pull-left'),
        Div(
            Field('mother_name', css_class='control-label'), 
            css_class='col-md-6'),
        css_class='row-fluid divs panel')
    ), 
)
```

By using this code, my form is looking very ugly means it is not well aligned. Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: Have you figured out how to set different field_class and label_class for individual fields?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it into the `widget`, just like `required` and the `placeholder`:

```
widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
    'class': 'special',
    'placeholder':'First Name',
    'required':True,
})
```

Comment: I have tried out it. It is not working for `label tag`